# How can one convert 64 character size of the devToken got in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken to the 32 characters size string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

While implementing Push Notification service in my application, I am facing very strange problem. In my case, I am using Server model of In-App purchase (and hence the content provider server is custom server provided by the client).

The server is providing an API that is used to register the device to the APNS. In that API, device token expected to be of 32 characters long (as written in apple documentation that the device token used to be send with the notification need to be of 32 bytes, I suppose).

My problem is, since we are getting 64 characters of String in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method, how can one convert it to 32 characters?
I mean will there not be a lost of data?
I am currently trimming the NSData to get the NSString only.

---

Update:
Can I use memcpy in iPhone? I got to know that it is only available in Mac OSx and not in iOS, is it correct?

---

Kindly suggest the way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the 64 byte sting hex encoded perhaps?

Comment: You mean to say that it can not be further converted to 32 characters of string?

Comment: How are you determining that it is 64 bytes?  NSLog?  data.length?  Post it, change a few bytes if necessary for security.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is 64 bytes, it looks 64 characters long string. And I suppose that 1 character occupies 1 byte.

Comment: I got to know that the string coming as a devToken in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is actually 32 characters string which was present as 64 bytes hex encoded and hence confusion was created. Thanks @CocoaFu for the hint.